# Hidden FloatingActionButton doesn't follow Snackbar

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

I am implementing FloatingActionButton that hides/shows when RecylerView is scrolling. But I have a problem. If FAB hides when SnackBar is visible and then appears after Snackbar is gone, FAB remains on the wrong position.

[It looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECyl6.png)

I use [this code](https://github.com/ianhanniballake/cheesesquare/blob/aefa8b57e61266e4ad51bef36e669d69f7fd749c/app/src/main/java/com/support/android/designlibdemo/ScrollAwareFABBehavior.java) for implementing. 
Tell me please how could I fix this bug.

Comment: Have you tried using the [most up to date code](https://github.com/ianhanniballake/cheesesquare/blob/scroll_aware_fab/app/src/main/java/com/support/android/designlibdemo/ScrollAwareFABBehavior.java)? You seem to be using an older revision.

Comment: @ianhanniballake  Same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: This has been fixed as part of the [Support Library 23.2.0](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html) release and the [related bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=195114) is now fixed.

*Original answer*

As seen in the [FloatingActionButton source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.java#505), the `updateFabTranslationForSnackbar` method does not update the translation when the `FloatingActionButton` is not visible.

You could manually call [ViewCompat.setTranslateY()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setTranslationY(android.view.View,%20float)) when you show()/hide(), but calculating the correct translation is not easy without direct access to the current Snackbar location. You might be better suited raising this as [bug at b.android.com](http://b.android.com) as fixing this internally would be much easier.

Comment: I'll add a couple of links here. This problem was raised in [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35074558/android-floating-action-button-not-returning-to-initial-position/35141898#35141898) and I gave an answer similar to what Ian has suggested above(though it's not ideal). [An issue has been filed here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200111&q=fab%20snackbar&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) by the person who asked that question.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you

Comment: Note: this has now been fixed in the 23.2 release!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32798807/floatingactionbutton-does-not-come-down-when-dismissing-snackbar implementation